# JasperReports on mobile platform

Tags: java, jsf, jasper-reports, ios

I have web application that uses JasperReports for PDF report generation. I'd like to write a mobile version of my application, specifically iPhone development (iOS). Will this be possible?

Comment: Can't you perform the PDF generation on a web server via SOAP, REST, etc. and then download it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That won't be possible for several reasons:

1. JasperReports needs Java, so it won't work on devices without Java e.g. iOS
2. Even if the mobile device supports Java it will probably be the Micro Edition (ME) that doesn't provide all basic classes used by JasperReports, e.g. java.awt.* to handle Fonts.

A possible solution would be to host a webservice that accepts a template and turns that into a PDF that gets return as a result, so you can display that in your app.

Comment: Yes I was afraid of this answer. My webpp does work on the iPhone via Safari, but I guess that really doens't quality it from being a mobile app...

Thanks for the input.

-C

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the new v4.2 if JasperReports Server.  Jaspersoft has published a Mobile SDK with it to enable the creation of native applications for the iPhone/iPad.  Basicallly it leverages web services to use a server to generate reports and provide them to the mobile application.